# Sorted assets on name or id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of collections (on left of my screen), that show their assets whenever the collection is clicked (right of screen). I am now trying to add a sort functionality of the assets based on a select tag (see render). Assets should be sorted by name by default, but a drop down allows the user to toggle between “Sort by id” and “Sort by name”. I am creating the assets in handleAssetsClick(). The problem that I am having is that I can't make the assets update without reclicking the collection and therefore activating the handleAssetsClick(). The handleAssetsClick is important because it makes the selection of which assets are part of each collection.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"
import {assets} from "./data.js"
import {FaStar} from "react-icons/fa"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections,
           assetsarr: assets,
           clickedassets: []
        }
    }

    handleAssetsClick(id){
      const clickedassetsdata = this.state.assetsarr.filter(asset => asset.collectionId === id)
      this.setState({
        clickedassets: clickedassetsdata
      })
    }

    makeMaster(idclick){
      const themasteridnr = this.state.clickedassets.filter(masterpot => masterpot.id === idclick)[0].id
      const newcollections = this.state.collectionsarr.slice()
      const index = this.state.clickedassets.filter(masterpot => masterpot.id === idclick)[0].collectionId - 1
      newcollections[index].masterAssetId = themasteridnr
      this.setState({   
        ...this.state,
        collectionsarr: newcollections
      })
    }

    getAssetPath(masterAssetId){
      const asset = this.state.assetsarr.find(x => x.id === masterAssetId)
      return asset ? require(`./${asset.path}`) : ''
    }

    getMasterId(assetnr){
      let idresult = this.state.collectionsarr.find(collection => collection.masterAssetId === assetnr)
      if(typeof idresult === "undefined"){
        return -1
      } else if (typeof idresult !== "undefined"){
        return idresult.masterAssetId
      } 
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Coding challenge</h1>
            
            <label>Sort assets by:</label>
            <select name="sorting">
                <option value="sortbyname">NAME</option>
                <option value="sortbyid">ID</option>
            </select>
            
            
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <p onClick={()=>this.handleAssetsClick(element.id)}>{element.name}</p>
                  <img src={this.getAssetPath(element.masterAssetId)} alt="pic"/>
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br> 
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="right">
                {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset => 
                  <div key={asset.id}>
                    <img src={require(`./${asset.path}`)} alt="pic"/>
                    <p>{asset.name}</p>
                    <p>{asset.id}</p>
                    {asset.id !== this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <button onClick={() => this.makeMaster(asset.id)}>Make master!</button> }
                    {asset.id === this.getMasterId(asset.id) && <FaStar />}
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                  </div>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

**data.js**

```
const collections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        masterAssetId: 13,
        tags: {
            name: "Cartoon",
            subTag: {
                name: "Simpsons family",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2014",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Super heroes",
        masterAssetId: 24,
        tags: {
            name: "DC Super heroes",
            subTag: {
                name: "2014",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Toy story",
        masterAssetId: 31,
        tags: {
            name: "Disney",
            subTag: {
                name: "Pixar",
                subTag: {
                    name: "Original movie",
                    subTag: {
                        name: "2010",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Ninjago",
        masterAssetId: 42,
        tags: {
            name: "Ninja",
            subTag: {
                name: "Secret Ninja Force",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2017",
                },
            },
        },
    },
];

const assets = [
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        path: "Homer.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Lisa Simpson",
        path: "Lisa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        path: "Bart.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        path: "Marge.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Grampa Simpson",
        path: "Grampa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Maggie Simpson",
        path: "Maggie.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        name: "Green Lantern",
        path: "Green lantern.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        name: "Flash",
        path: "Flash.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 23,
        name: "Batman",
        path: "Batman.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 24,
        name: "Superman",
        path: "Superman.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 31,
        name: "Buzz Lightyear",
        path: "Buzz.jpg",
        collectionId: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "Alien",
        path: "Alien.jpg",
        collectionId: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 41,
        name: "Spinjitzu training Nya",
        path: "Nya.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 42,
        name: "Master Wu",
        path: "Wu.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 43,
        name: "Lloyd",
        path: "Lloyd.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
];

export {collections}
export {assets}
```

Comment: Did you try using componentDidUpdate lifecycle method and calling a= handleAssetsClick inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onChange` handler to the select that sets the sort in state. If there's already a 'clickedassets' array in state, you can update it accordingly. You might need to keep track of the clicked id in addition to its contents so you can re-run whatever filtering, etc. you're doing.

```
// define whatever sort functions you need
const sort = {
  'name': (a, b) => localeCompare(a.name, b.name), // or whatever
  'id': (a, b) => localeCompare(a.id, b.id),
}

// save sort selection in state and re-trigger handleAssetsClick
onSortChange({target: {value}}) {
  const {selectedId} = this.state;
  this.setState({ sort: value });
  if (selectedId) {
    this.handleAssetsClick(selectedId);
  }
}

// might want to rename this since it may be called without a click
handleAssetsClick(id){
  const {
    assetsarr,
    sort = 'id' // get selected sort, default to 'id'
  } = this.state;

  const clickedassetsdata = assetsarr
    .filter(asset => asset.collectionId === id)
    .sort(sort[sort]); // sort according to state.sort value

  this.setState({
    selectedId: id,
    clickedassets: clickedassetsdata
  });
}


<select name="sorting" onChange={onSortChange}>
  {
    // render select options based on available sort functions
    Object.keys(sort).map(sortOption => (
      <option key={sortOption}>{sortOption}</option>
    ))
  }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you are asking how to sort `clickedassets` without having to call `handleAssetsClick` again.

You wrote:

> I can't make the assets update without reclicking the collection.

In fact, you can since you are storing `clickedassets` in the state of the `App` component.

First, add a new property to the state which keeps track of which sorting mode is selected by storing the value of your `select` element. Set its initial value to `'sortbyname'` since you want the assets to be sorted by name by default:

```
this.state = {
    [...]
    assetsSortingMode: 'sortbyname'
}
```

Then, add the following attributes to your `select` element which connect it with your state:

```
<select name="sorting" value={this.state.assetsSortingMode} onChange={e => this.setState({assetsSortingMode: e.target.value})}>
    [...]
</select>
```

Then, further down in your render method, change:

```
<div className="right">
    {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset =>
        [...]
    )}
</div>
```

to:

```
<div className="right">
    {getSortedAssets().map(asset =>
        [...]
    )}
</div>
```

and add the following function to your component:

```
getSortedAssets() {
    if(this.state.assetsSortingMode === 'sortbyname') {
        // sort by name alphabetically
        return this.state.clickedassets.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    }
    else if(this.state.assetsSortingMode === 'sortbyid') {
        // sort by id ascending
        return this.state.clickedassets.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }

    return [];
}
```

This should do the trick but I haven't tested this code.